# Memory leak in Apple's LazyTableImages Sample code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, memory-leaks

I am using a modified version of [LazyTableImages sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009394) provided by apple. During testing, found there are few memory leaks in the code. I have tested the original code given by apple and found the same leaks(464 Bites).
[image] Anybody managed to fix this? appreciate your help.

Comment: this is not a big trouble unless your application get crashed ...and also you can remove this leak by auto releasing  the object within the connection did finish loading method

Comment: @Freezing Fire, Thanks for the suggestion, but I am receiving   “EXC_BAD_ACCESS” after autoreleasing it. This is not a big leak as it wont grows over time, but I am trying to get it right.

Comment: i tried Build and Analyze and got anything wrong with that.

Comment: @makboney The leak appears after image download. I used instruments.

Answer (score 1):

If you have recieved “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”, some object delete from memory. You should use NSZombie, which detected deleted object.

Comment: This error is caused by autoreleasing the parser. Any idea why an autorelease cause this?

Comment: May be you use object with autorelease in some function, and then you call object in another function, but this object has already deleted from memory.